# Alternate audio tracks with HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: ios, cocoa, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm generating a list of available audio tracks when an HLS stream is ready to play.  I can access the available audio tracks just fine, but I'm having difficulty extracting the correct 'Title' for each track.

I'm using [Apple's test stream](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8) which has two audio tracks.  I extract the tracks with this...

```
availableAudioTrackList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
AVMediaSelectionGroup *audioTracks = [player.currentItem.asset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicAudible];
for (int i = 0; i < [audioTracks.options count]; i++) {
    AVMediaSelectionOption *opt = audioTracks.options[i];
    NSLog(@"Opt: %@", opt);
    [availableAudioTrackList insertObject:opt.displayName atIndex:i];
}
NSLog(@"Audio Track Array: %@", availableAudioTrackList);
```

My output shows that 'opt.displayName' does not give the title of BipBop Audio 1 and BipBop Audio 2 (these are the distinguishing names I want to be able to use).

```
... Opt: <AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x15dad0d0, locale = en, mediaType = 'soun', title = BipBop Audio 1, default = YES> 
... Opt: <AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x15dad100, locale = en, mediaType = 'soun', title = BipBop Audio 2>

...Audio Track Array: ( English, English )
```

Any idea how/if I can extract the title from the AVMediaSelectionOption object?

Thanks!

Comment: What is in the `displayName` property?

Comment: @vipw, that's what I'm confused about.  I did a similar call for generating the subtitles in the player item, and it would return AVMediaSelectionOption's title.  My output shows that title for the audio track is "BipBop Audio 1", and this is the string that I'm trying to access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to fetch it from metadata as follows

```
    NSArray *metaDatas = [AVMetadataItem metadataItemsFromArray:opt.commonMetadata withKey:@"title" keySpace:@"comn"];
    if (metaDatas.count > 0) {
      NSString *title = ((AVMetadataItem*)[metaDatas objectAtIndex:0]).stringValue;
      NSLog(@"title: %@", title);
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct solution!  Thanks so much!  After I posted this question, I tabled this issue and only just came back to it, so good timing.  I made one edit to your solution, as `opt` was not an NSArray, but it was fixed by accessing it's commonMetadata property.  Again THANK YOU!