# How to switch audio track in m3u8 video stream?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, m3u8

I need to switch audio track in received video stream with format m3u8, how can i do this?
It's possible? How to detect them? (i receive stream HLS, 10seconds segments .ts, format MPEG-2, Transport Stream)

Comment: You only want to play an audio from a m8u3 video file?

Comment: No, audio and video together, but also can switch audiotracks)

Comment: Your m3u8 link should contain both audio and video. then just use media player to play it with that link

Comment: i can play with that link, but how i can switch between two audiotracks, when video is playing?

Comment: You mean switching between 2 links or you have 2 audio tracks in 1 link ?

Comment: Yes, i have 2 audio tracks in 1 stream link

Comment: I know that its an old question, but do you remember/did you ever find the solution to switch between audio tracks in the same video?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question:

[Alternate audio tracks with HTTP Live Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551399/alternate-audio-tracks-with-http-live-streaming)

I managed to retrieve the audio tracks from an HLS stream encoded with Fairplay (I retrieve the tracks after decoding the content). The stream has two different audios, English and Spanish, so I use a dictionary to hold each audio extracted from the HLS stream and ease the switching between them.

Each audio is represented by an AVMediaSelectionOption object, and that's the object you have to pass to your AVPlayerItem object (in the select method) to do the audio switching.

```
let mediaSelectionGroup = self.player!.currentItem!.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristicAudible)!
        print("ASSET AUDIO TRACKS: \(mediaSelectionGroup)")

self.mediaSelectionOptions = Dictionary<String, AVMediaSelectionOption>()

    for mediaSelectionOption in self.mediaSelectionGroup!.options {
        if let locale = mediaSelectionOption.locale, let languageCode = locale.languageCode {
            if languageCode == "en" {
                self.mediaSelectionOptions!["Inglés"] = mediaSelectionOption
            } else if languageCode == "es" {
                self.mediaSelectionOptions!["Español"] = mediaSelectionOption
            }
        }
    }

// Set Spanish audio
self.player!.currentItem!.select(
                self.audioManager!.mediaSelectionOptions!["Español"],
                in: mediaSelectionGroup
            )

// Set English audio
self.player!.currentItem!.select(
                self.audioManager!.mediaSelectionOptions!["Inglés"],
                in: mediaSelectionGroup
            )
```

Hope it helps!